# python, windows 7: ImportError: cannot import name X

Tags: python, importerror, construct

I'm working with two files: `construct\core.py` and `USBtransport.py`. Below is the relevant code from both files:

construct\core.py:

```
class Range(Subconstruct):  
    __slots__ = ["min", "max"]
    def __init__(self, min, max, subcon):
        super(Range, self).__init__(subcon)
        self.min = min
        self.max = max
....
```

where Subconstruct is a subclass of Construct which were both defined earlier in the code.

USBtransport.py:

```
from construct import Subconstruct
from construct import (
Bytes, Container, Embedded, Enum, ExprAdapter, Int16ul, Int32ul, Pass, 
Struct, Range,
)
```

I run into this error when trying to run USBtransport.py:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Range'
```

I've looked at similar posts about this error and they seem to all stem from circular importing. However I don't think that's the issue here since `core.py` never calls any classes from `USBtransport.py`. I'm also able to import other `Subconstruct` objects from `core.py` without problems.

I also don't think the error stems from the code inside class `Range(Subconstruct)` since I get the same error when I comment out all the code inside and just try to import an empty class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. It seems that Range is defined in core.py, not in construct.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I should have clarified that core.py is a file in the folder construct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the right version of [Construct](https://construct.readthedocs.io/)?

According to https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transition29.html , `Range` was removed in 2.9, so you might want to install 2.8.x.

> Range removed, GreedyRange does not support [:] syntax

Comment: I'm using Construct 2.8.22, which has Range defined in it

Comment: If it helps, the full code for USBtransport is here: https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/sequoia-ptpy/blob/master/ptpy/transports/usb.py

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned `core.py` is not your code either, but `construct/core.py`.

Comment: Anyway, without further information about what you're doing and what exactly is importing these things, I'm not sure I can decipher this situation much more. :(